# Add columns to select statement of ssis package during runtime

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package, etl, dynamic-sql

I have a simple package that move data from source to destination, however I want to add new column during run time.
example source table contains columns a, b and c.
I have a SQL task at the beginning of the package that creates a new column like a +'_'+ b based on values from another table.
My question is how to add this columns to the source of the package during run time.

Comment: use conditional split and then go with derived column

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to add a derived column from 2 columns in the first table and add them in to a second table.

Here's a basic example of how you can do this (using temp tables for illustration purposes only).

First, create a temp table with 2 columns and a single row:

```
SELECT 'a' AS ColA, 'b' AS ColB
INTO #tmp
```

Next create a temp table to insert the values and a derived column (`ColC`):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp2 (ColA VARCHAR(1), ColB VARCHAR(1), ColC VARCHAR(3))
```

Insert the data from the first table and combine `ColA + '_' + ColB`:

```
INSERT INTO #tmp2
        ( ColA, ColB, ColC )
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColA + '_' + ColB
FROM #tmp

SELECT * FROM #tmp2
```

Output:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC
--------------------
a       b       a_b
```